# probel with calling method paintComponet(Graphics g) in class render from class Snake

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I am new to java gaming.I am trying to call `paintComponent` in render class that extends JPanel from Snake class using the code below. however i do not know where i am going wrong. it is able to call the constructor of render and not `paintComponent` method.

```
public class Snake implements ActionListener 
{
    public Timer t=new Timer(20,this);
    public Render render;
    public JFrame frame;
    public Toolkit toolkit;
    public static Snake s;
    public Snake()
    {
     toolkit=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
     frame=new JFrame();
     //MenuBar menubar=new MenuBar();
     render=new Render();
     frame.setTitle("Nikitha's Snake");
     frame.setVisible(true);
     frame.setSize(800,700);
     frame.setLocation(toolkit.getScreenSize().width/2,            toolkit.getScreenSize().height/2);
     frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.add(render);

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      JMenuBar menubar=new JMenuBar(); 
      JMenu file=new JMenu("File");
      menubar.add(file);
      JMenuItem newgame=new JMenuItem("new game");
      file.add(newgame);
      JMenu edit=new JMenu("Edit");
      menubar.add(edit);
      JMenuItem exit=new JMenuItem("Exit");
      edit.add(exit);
      frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);   


      exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {
          //@Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          System.exit(0);}
      });
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   t.start();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        s = new Snake();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {
        //System.out.println("a");
        render.repaint();
    }  
}




package snake;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("Serial")
public class Render extends JPanel{

public static int curcolor=0;    
  public void PaintComponent(Graphics g)
        {      
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("i am inside render class");
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 700);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`PaintComponent` != `paintComponent`

Remember, Java is case sensitive.

It's highly recommended when overriding methods, you use the `@Override` annotation, as this will generate a compiler error when you get it wrong.

```
public class Render extends JPanel{ 

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i literally spent a day trying to solve that:D